# Find and rename files adding part of the path to filename

Tags: shell-script, rename

I have a folder with two level of subfolders inside it. Inside the second subfolder, there is a jpg file. All the jpg have the same name: `cover.jpg`

Example:

```
/home/user/folder001/folderAAA/cover.jpg
/home/user/folder002/folderBBB/cover.jpg
[...]
/home/user/folder999/folderZZZ/cover.jpg
```

I need to find (and copy to a new folder) all `cover.jpg` files and rename them adding to its filename (as prefix) the name of the first and second subfolder.

Example:
After the intended operation, the content ot `/home/user1/newfolder` must be:

```
folder001_folderAAA_cover.jpg
folder002_folderBBB_cover.jpg
[...]
folder999_folderZZZ_cover.jpg
```

Comment: Is there a question here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#! /bin/bash

target_dir_path="/copy/here"

for file in folder*/*/*.jpg; do
        l1="${file%%/*}"
        l2="${file#*/}"
        l2="${l2%%/*}"
        filename="${file##*/}"
        target_file_name="${l1}_${l2}_${filename}"
        echo cp "$file" "${target_dir_path}/${target_file_name}"
done
```

Remove the `echo` if it does what you want.

Comment: Well, that worked! but I must have done something wrong because I got errors (L1: "filename" comand not found). I cd'ed into the folder in question and did:#! /bin/bash

target_dir_path="/home/user/results"

for file in folder */*/*.jpg; do
        "$file"
        # folder001/folderAAA/cover.jpg
        l1="${file%%/*}"
        "   L1: ${l1}"
        l2="${file#*/}"
        l2="${l2%%/*}"
        "   L2: ${l2}"
        filename="${file##*/}"
        "   filename: ${filename}"
        target_file_name="${l1}_${l2}_${filename}"
        cp "$file" "${target_dir_path}/${target_file_name}"
done

Comment: @user68563 Sorry, I forgot to delete the debug stuff. You should remove the `echo` only in the `cp` line.

Comment: Thank you! Now it did work perfectly! Just had to remove the word "folder" on line 5: 
#! /bin/bash

target_dir_path="/home/user/results"

for file in */*/*.jpg; do
        l1="${file%%/*}"
        l2="${file#*/}"
        l2="${l2%%/*}"
        filename="${file##*/}"
        target_file_name="${l1}_${l2}_${filename}"
        cp "$file" "${target_dir_path}/${target_file_name}"
done

Comment: hey, a strange thing happened on my reply. I wrote:
for file in * / * / *.jpg; do
(without the spaces, just so it doesn't happen again this time)
but i showed only:
for file in / * /.jpg; do
it can't be my mistake because I pasted my answer from a text file!

Comment: sorry for the bad formatting, it was my first question and I don't know yet how to write well in here. I will try to learn soon, though. Regards

Comment: @user68563 Have a look at the help page: https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting  See the block "Comment Formatting". Probably this problem disappears if you use backticks to mark code. If this works then you should accept the answer so that the others see that this question is done: https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 3):

This can be easily achieved the help of sed command.
Find the list of files which needs to be renamed and with sed/echo of file path we can achieve the requirement.

```
cd /home/user
for fl_nm in $(find . -type f -name "cover.jpg")
do
echo copying the file with desired name to new folder : $fl_nm
cp $fl_nm /home/user1/newfolder/$(echo ${i#*/*} | sed 's/\//_/g')
#Above copy command ignores the find result which extracts only file path from ./**file_path**
done
```

All the files with name cover.jpg will be copied to /home/user1/newfolder
    with the file name with respective folder details in file name.

Comment: I changed it to cp $fl_nm /home/user1/newfolder/$(echo $fl_nm | sed 's/\//_/g') and it worked!  I also removed the first "_" in the file name by adding a new pipe "|" with the sed command.

Answer (score 2):

In zsh, put [`autoload zmv`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-zmv) in your `.zshrc` (or run that one on your command line to experiment with it), then:

```
mkdir /home/user1/newfolder
zmv '/home/user/(*)/(*)/(cover.jpg)' '/home/user1/newfolder/${1}_${2}_${3}'
```

Every file that matches the pattern on the left-hand side is renamed to the replacement text on the right-hand side. `*` means “any sequence of characters”. On the right-hand side, `${1}`, `${2}` and `${3}` are replaced respectively by the portion of the source path matched by the first, second and third parenthesised group in the pattern.

Instead of using explicit grouping, you can request each wildcard to be automatically made a group of its own:

```
zmv -w '/home/user/*/*/cover.jpg' '/home/user1/newfolder/${1}_${2}_cover.jpg'
```

Or even:

```
zmv -W '/home/user/*/*/cover.jpg' '/home/user1/newfolder/*_*_cover.jpg'
```

Some even go as far as adding:

```
alias zmmv='noglob zmv -W'
```

to there `~/.zshrc` so as to be able to write:

```
zmmv /home/user/*/*/cover.jpg /home/user1/newfolder/*_*_cover.jpg
```